# Why are Safari Extension toolbar icons blue?

Tags: macos, safari, icon, safari-extensions

I've recently installed some [Safari Extensions](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/get-extensions-sfri32508/mac) via the Mac App Store.

[image: Blue Safari Extension icons.]

After installing, they show up in my toolbar. The Safari Extension icons have an annoying blue tint color.

What does the blue color mean? Is there any way to make them grayscale to match the other Safari toolbar icons?

Comment: https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/2021-7-7.html

Comment: https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/blues.html

Answer (score 5):

The color is decided by the developer and signals that the extension is active. For example, on the favorites menu (blank tab) all my extensions are   inactive and grey:
[image]

While when on a website, my extensions are active and display the programmed color. It isn't always blue. For example, Grammarly is green.[image]

Edit: incorporating Mathias Winkleman’s answer, some developers choose default color, which is your accent color. By default it is blue, but grey does not change the icons to grey.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what @anonymous said, here's how you can (lightly) influence the color: the default, blue in your case, follows the setting for **Accent colour** in **Preferences** ▶ **General**.

One of the options for that setting is grey. Unfortunately, that happens to be the exception, with icons reverting to blue when it is selected.

[image: Screenshot of General preference pane showing Accent colours]

If, however, you never actually need to click on the icons, you can right-click on the toolbar, choose **customize**, and remove them. The extensions will continue to work as before.